# .Net 3.5 Winforms Basic Dialog with Label Autosize for custom text contents

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, dialog

I want a form containing:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Dialog Title                          X|
+----------------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------+
|icon   |                                |
|32x32px| One-line label (Heading)       |
|       +--------------------------------+
|       |                                |
|       | Message label with auto-wrap   |
|       | text according to any given    |
|       | string.                        |
+-------+--------------------------------+
| row for dialog buttons...              |
+----------------------------------------+
```

I'll gladly answer any questions; the basic idea is still simple (though *I* cannot get it to work): Given any message string containing possible newlines the dialog (a Form) should keep its width but grow vertically depending on the message.

Any way how this can be done?

Comment: Too many downvotes in this thread to risk an answer.

Comment: Use a [`TaskDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760540.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I think the component that you will find most useful is `TableLayoutPanel`. Find it under “Containers” in the Toolbox. Set the `TableLayoutPanel`’s `Dock = Fill`.

You can use it to lay out the controls in columns and rows. Once a control is inside the `TableLayoutPanel`, you can use the `ColumnSpan` property on such a control to span it across multiple columns; I’d use this for the button row at the bottom, i.e. make a new panel for the button row and put the buttons inside that. For the icon, of course, use `RowSpan` instead.

Experiment with various values of `Anchor`, `AutoSize`  and `AutoSizeMode` for some of the controls, especially the message label that you want to grow automatically. If you set the `TableLayoutPanel` and the `Form` to `AutoSize = true`, then the window will grow automatically with the text contents.

Answer (score 1):

You could try handling the `TextChanged` event of the label and measure the size of the string using something like this:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
SizeF s = g.MeasureString(yourLabel.Text, yourLabel.Font, yourLabel.Width);
```

After this, knowing the sizes of the other controls you can modify the size of the window accordingly. I am assuming that you only want to resize the window vertically.

Comment: Rather than use `Graphics.MeasureString`, use `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` - Text renderer provides a more accurate result (and no need to create a Graphics object yourself too).

Answer (score 0):

Try a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) for the layout and set its `Dock` property to `Fill` to occupy the entire `Form`. Then plop your "one-line" and "message" labels into their respective cells and set their `Dock` properties to `Fill` to occupy the entire cell.

If you really want to resize the entire Form to fit any message at runtime, you may have to use [`Graphics.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) to determine the area you need to contain the string and then resize the form to contain that area.

Answer (score -1):

You might try to ask for the position of the last character

```
TextBox box = new TextBox();
box.Text = "...";
var positionOfLastCharacter = box.GetPositionFromCharIndex(box.TextLength);
```

The you can calculate the necessary height of the textbox and the form.

**Edit:** That will give you the top left corner of the last character, you should add 10px or so to make the last line fit.

Answer (score -2):

Create your own new Form and show it as a dialog box. You can put whatever/however you want on that form.

[Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp) you have a tutorial that will show you how to do the *hardest* part.